# VBA: Organizing Chart Objects in worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I have a workbook with several Chart Sheets. I want to create a sheet where all charts can be easily found all at once, so I can rapidly copy and then paste them in powerpoint presentations.

My code can copy, paste and change the size of each chart sheet just fine. The trouble comes when I try to organize them in the sheet.

The thing is that the code pastes them all in a single line. If, for instance, I have a large number of charts, finding a specific one could take too much time.

I would like to organize all charts in something of this sort, disposing a specific number of charts for each row (say, for instance, 2 charts per row).

[image]

I tried to use the `.left` property for charts, but it aligns all charts to the same column (and please notice that this is not my intention).

I have also tried to introduce a variable for the rows, but I have trouble in controlling when the variable should "jump" for the next row to paste the chart.

Any ideas if this is feasible?

```
Sub PasteCharts()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Cht As Chart
Dim Cht_ob As ChartObject

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False


'k is the column number for the address where the chart is to be pasted
k = -1
For Each Cht In wb.Charts

    k = k + 1
    Cht.Activate
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy

    Sheets("Gráficos").Select
    Cells(2, (k * 10) + 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

Next Cht


'Changes the size of each chart pasted in the specific sheet
For Each Cht_ob In Sheets("Gráficos").ChartObjects
With Cht_ob
    .Height = 453.5433070866
    .Width = 453.5433070866

End With

Next Cht_ob


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True


MsgBox ("All Charts were pasted successfully")
End Sub
```

Comment: where are all your original charts ? in multiple worksheets in your workbook? in a single sheet? or placed as chart sheets ?

Comment: The original all charts are placed as chart sheets, all in the same workbook.

Comment: have you tried any of the solutions you got below ? any feedback ?

Comment: Both solutions work wonderfully!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below, it will copy>>paste all chartsheet in your workbook to "Gráficos" sheet.

Currently, it will paste the odd charts in Column A, and the even charts at Column K (you can modify easily in the code).

The gap between each 2 charts is 30 rows (also can be modified in the code below).

To place a chart in a certain cell, you need to use the `ChartObject` and use it's `.Top` and `.Left` properties.

The syntax to place a chart in Cell A1 is:

`Cht_ob.Top = Sheets("Charts").Range("A1").Top`

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub PasteCharts()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Cht As Chart
Dim Cht_ob As ChartObject
Dim k As Long
Dim ChartRowCount As Long

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

k = 0 ' row number, increment every other 2 charts
ChartRowCount = 1 ' column number, either 1 or 2
For Each Cht In wb.Charts
    Cht.ChartArea.Copy ' copy chart        
    Sheets("Gráficos").Paste ' paste chart

    Set Cht_ob = Sheets("Gráficos").ChartObjects(Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects.Count)  ' set chart object to pasted chart

    With Cht_ob
        If ChartRowCount = 1 Then
            .Top = Sheets("Gráficos").Range("A" & 1 + 30 * k).Top ' modify the top position
            .Left = Sheets("Gráficos").Range("A" & 1 + 30 * k).Left ' modify the left position

            ChartRowCount = ChartRowCount + 1
        Else ' ChartRowCount = 2
            .Top = Sheets("Gráficos").Range("K" & 1 + 30 * k).Top ' modify the top position
            .Left = Sheets("Gráficos").Range("K" & 1 + 30 * k).Left  ' modify the left position

            ChartRowCount = 1
            k = k + 1
        End If

        .Height = 453.5433070866
        .Width = 453.5433070866
    End With
Next Cht

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True

MsgBox ("All Charts were pasted successfully")

End Sub
```

Comment: We were working on it simultaneously :). Well, both should work, mine just suggests to set coordinates instead of using cells.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest another method that proceeds directly on the coordinates, not on the cells:

```
Sub PasteCharts()
    Dim cht As Chart, cht_ob As ChartObject, left As Long, top As Long
    Dim chartWidth As Long, chartHeight As Long, chartsPerRow As Long
    chartWidth = 200: chartHeight = 200: chartsPerRow = 4  ' <-- Set to your choice

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False: Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo Cleanup
    For Each cht In ThisWorkbook.Charts
        Set cht_ob = Worksheets("Gráficos").ChartObjects.Add(left, top, chartWidth, chartHeight)
        cht.ChartArea.Copy
        cht_ob.Chart.Paste

        'adjust coordinates for next  chart object
        left = left + chartWidth
        If left > chartsPerRow * chartWidth * 0.99 Then
            left = 0
            top = top + chartHeight
        End If
    Next
    msgBox ("All Charts were pasted successfully")
Cleanup:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True: Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```